# Play Framework - Checkbox processing

Tags: forms, process, checkbox, playframework

How do I process a checkbox input in Play! Framework? Should I catch the value as a String at the controller? How to get what values
are checked by a user?

This is the html code of my checkbox

```
#{list items:categories, as:'category'}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="category" id="category-${category.name}" value="${category.id}" /><label for="category-${category.name}"> ${category.name}</label></td>
    </tr>
#{/list}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a `List<String> category` in your form action, you will get a list of value of checked items.

Answer (score 0):

> To show the state of a specific term (actually there are more terms,
>   think about a Project having multiple terms, that’s why you see the
>   name being selectedTerms) in a view I did:
>
> ```
> #{form @ProjectController.update(project.alias), enctype:'multipart/form-data', class:'well form-horizontal'}
> #{list terms, as:'term'}
> <input type="checkbox" name="selectedTerms" value="${term.name}"/>
> <span>${term.name}<span>
> #{/list}
> #{/form}
> ```
>
> Now the main question is: how do I know which of these terms were
>   selected by the user?
>
> Well, Play let me to define these terms as a List, check below:
>
> ```
> public static void update(String alias, List<String> selectedTerms) {
> //play with selected terms
> }
> ```
>
> Please note: selectedTerms list will contain ONLY the terms which are
>   selected (TRUE) by the user. Because I have their names (or ids or
>   what you want) all the problems are solved:)
>
> Ps: You will probably ask: how do you show these in the view after you
>   saved them in db?
>
> ```
> #{list terms, as:'term'}
> <input type="checkbox" name="selectedTerms" value="${term.name}" ${term.selected ? 'checked':''}/>
> <span>${term.name}</span>
> #{/list}
> ```

Thanks to Cristian Boariu, here is the link for your inspiration:

http://crisdev.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/play-framework-get-checkbox-value-from-view-in-controller/