# Play Framework submitting boolean values with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, playframework, playframework-2.3

Using Play 2.3.x I am trying to understand how checkboxes are handled in forms. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499279/play-framework-checkbox-processing) seems like an outdated solution for an older version of Play. I understand that [checkbox info will only be posted if checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked), but I've created a small sample app and no info is posted even if I check the boxes. Here is my sample "Hello World" application

**Model**

```
public static class Hello {
    @Required public String name;
    @Required @Min(1) @Max(100) public Integer repeat;
    public String color;
    public Boolean box1;
    public Boolean box2;
}
```

**View**

```
    @* For brevity, here is the checkbox code *@
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
         name="@helloForm("box1").name"
         value="@helloForm("box1").value"> Box 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
         name="@helloForm("box2").name"
         value="@helloForm("box2").value"> Box 2
    </label>
```

**Controller**

```
public static Result sayHello() {
    Form<Hello> form = Form.form(Hello.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(index.render(form));
    } else {
        Hello data = form.get();
        Logger.debug("Box 1 was " + data.box1);
        Logger.debug("Box 2 was " + data.box2);
        return ok(
                hello.render(data.name, data.repeat, data.color)
        );
    }
}
```

I want to see if I can get the boolean true/false information printed in the debug statements. Right now even if I click both boxes and submit, they return as `null`. Also, I know that there is a view helper for checkboxes, but I want to understand how to get this working using a custom view. **Any advice on how to use checkboxes to map Boolean attributes?**

PS - [full code is here if you'd like to try it](https://github.com/kjorg50/play-2.3-hello-world/tree/checkbox)

Comment: Did you check in the Network tab of Firefox, Chrome or whichever browser you are using what is actually being sent to the server?

Then you can know if the error is in the controller (and the binding) or is directly in the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine you have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" checked="checked" value="true"> I have a box1
```

The field with name `box1` will be sent to the server as `true` whenever the checkbox is clicked (or checked). When is not checked, nothing will be sent for this field.

What I do is to set in the model (in your case, the class Hello),the Boolean field by default to false:

```
public Boolean box1=false;
public Boolean box2=false;
```

In this case, when the `bindFromRequest()` occurs and the POST method did not send any value for the field `box1` and/or `box2`, the fields will be filled with the default (false) value.

On the view, the only thing you will need, is as follows (I don't use the play helper):

```
<input type="checkbox"
     name="@helloForm("box1").name"
     value="true" 
     @if(helloForm("box1").value.contains("true")){checked="checked"}> Box 1
```

This will check your checkbox if the field was sent to the view as `true`

Comment: for me the getOrElse didn't work, here is the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22392741/3716114

Comment: Worked for me exactly like that in a custom field constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Boolean is always null (in all cases).