# Can't set "checked" with if in input

Tags: html, intellij-idea, playframework

Im not able to set an input to "checked" if e.g. a string is not null.
I have no idea why, I googled a lot but nothing worked.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889907/5859685) was the best I found but is seems to be wrong... at least it doesn't work for me.

[image]

This is the code I have for now:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="autowarn" value="checked" @if(autowarnVar != null){checked}>
```

IntelliJ tells me that the Tag is not closed, but it is, so where is the mistake?..
I haven't worked much with play until now, but I have other examples where it works, so I'm confused why it sometimes works an sometimes not?

Comment: Do you get a compile-time error when you actually compile the code above? I ask because I use `@if( condition ) { checked }` frequently, without compile issues. It looks like a possible intellij parsing problem.

Comment: I was not able to compile and run the code above. Got the same error then just in the browser and console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a `checked` value to checked attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="autowarn" value="checked"
@if(autowarnVar != null){checked="checked"}>
```